# Noob applescript curl

Tags: api, curl, applescript

Sorry it's a basic question as I'm a applescript noob.

I have a curl POST request in cli that looks like this

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer TOKEN" \
 https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks \
 --data-urlencode "assignee=IDNUMBER" \
 --data-urlencode "notes=TASKNOTE" \
 --data-urlencode "name=TASKNAME" \
 --data-urlencode "workspace=WORKSPACEID" \
 --data-urlencode "project=PROJECTID"
```

This POST works fine, and returns what I need. However I want to have similar script ran in applescript, via the 'do shell script' command. How would it look? I have spent time searching online & tutorials but unable to find right method, as I'm still learning :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it's the same syntax replacing the double quotes with single quotes and removing the backslash line separators

```
do shell script "curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer TOKEN' https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks --data-urlencode 'assignee=IDNUMBER' --data-urlencode 'notes=TASKNOTE' --data-urlencode 'name=TASKNAME' --data-urlencode 'workspace=WORKSPACEID' --data-urlencode 'project=PROJECTID'"
```

Comment: Appreciate the help :) sorry it was so basic